# Why all three Title column does not displayed in "Edit in Gridview" in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, title-column

We know that we have three Title column in SharePoint list to add into list views,

- Title
- Title (linked to an item with edit menu)
- Title (linked to an item)

But when I add all 3 Title columns in Edit Grid View, list displays only 2 Title column and not all three.

Any reason why it is happening? I thought it is by design, but I am unable to find any documentation or any article reference that mention this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Only one Title column is shown in grid view, because they are all variations of the same Title column. It wouldn't make sense to display the same column three times in grid view.

Comment: I understand your point. Currently, there are two visible Title columns in the GridView, which raises the question: if we can display two Title columns, why not three?

Comment: Because you cannot click the edit menu for "Title (linked to an item with edit menu)" in grid view.

Comment: I actually found that only one Title column shows for me when I'm editing in grid view.